# How can I do multi-dimensional matrix multiplication?

Tags: matlab

I have an array (A) 3500x7500x10.

And a matrix (B) 3500x7500.

So I want to do element-by-element multiplication B with each of the 10 pages of A.

Obviously, this doesn't work.

```
A = A(:,:,:).*B;
```

I know how to do it in a loop, but is there is a vectorized way of doing it?

Comment: `C=A.*repmat(B,1,1,10);`

Comment: @Adiel: that uses a great deal of additional memory. Instead: `C=bsxfun(@times,A,B);`, which is a bit faster as well (at least for the example matrices). Feel free to use this to write an answer as I'm on mobile.

Comment: Thanks @horchler. Don't like to write answers of one line..

Comment: @Adiel Apologies.  I closed this with a duplicate before seeing your intent to write an answer.  There was an answer already established that I marked as a duplicate.  If I had known you wanted to write an answer, I would have left it and let you have the rep.

Comment: @rayryeng No need to apologize. From the beginning, I wrote just a comment because I didn't want to write it as an answer. As I said to horchler, I don't like to write so short and basically answers. (and usually, also too lazy to write detailed ones...). Thanks